# Why does Craft set no-cache headers for all requests?

Tags: cache

Craft seems to be setting headers to tell the browser not to cache anything it serves, which seems bad.

`Cache-Control:no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0`

Why it do dat?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Craft doesn't explicitly set *any* caching headers in the response, but you can control exactly how you want your caching headers to behave from your templates with the [{% header %}](http://buildwithcraft.com/docs/templating/header) tag.

For example:

```
{# Tell the browser to cache this page for 30 days #}
{% set expiry = now|date_modify('+30 days') %}

{% header "Cache-Control: max-age=" ~ expiry.timestamp %}
{% header "Pragma: cache" %}
{% header "Expires: " ~ expiry|date('D, d M Y H:i:s', 'GMT') ~ " GMT" %}
```

By default PHP has the [session_cache_limiter()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-cache-limiter.php) method set to `nocache`, which is probably what you're seeing.

Comment: Hmmm...It seems like _something_ is (Yii or Craft) unless I'm confused.

Request headers for a static (non-craft request):
```HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Thu, 18 Sep 2014 01:44:49 GMT
Server: Apache
Last-Modified: Thu, 18 Sep 2014 01:44:48 GMT
Accept-Ranges: bytes
Cache-Control: max-age=0
Expires: Thu, 18 Sep 2014 01:44:49 GMT
Vary: Accept-Encoding
Content-Encoding: gzip
X-UA-Compatible: IE=edge
Content-Length: 26
Keep-Alive: timeout=5, max=100
Connection: Keep-Alive
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8```

Here's one from Craft:
```

Comment: Maybe Apache sets them by default if nothing has already been set?

Comment: Response header examples below (non-pertinent headers removed)

Response headers for a static (non-Craft request):
```HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Thu, 18 Sep 2014 01:44:49 GMT
Last-Modified: Thu, 18 Sep 2014 01:44:48 GMT
Cache-Control: max-age=0
Expires: Thu, 18 Sep 2014 01:44:49 GMT
```

Here's one from Craft:
```HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Max-Age=300; path=/
Expires: Thu, 19 Nov 1981 08:52:00 GMT
Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0
Pragma: no-cache
```

Comment: The only related header I've seen Apache set by default is `Cache-Control: max-age=0`

Comment: If you look at craft/app/services/TemplateService->renderTemplate(), you can see the headers Craft will set when rendering a template.

Comment: Maybe a php.ini thing?  Really strange.

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/session.configuration.php#ini.session.cache-limiter

Comment: Weird. I tested it by just bailing out of the top of index.php with an `exit('Hello');` - no no-cache headers. Once I let Craft run though, I see them. Are you not seeing the Cache-Control/Pragma headers on your Craft installs?

Comment: For the hell of it I checked the response headers on http://straightupcraft.com/ and I see the same thing.

Comment: Right... because session_cache_limiter() kicks in as soon as PHP's session_start() gets called, which won't have happened at the top of the root index.php. Craft/Yii will call that as soon as HttpSessionService->init() gets invoked in a request.

Comment: You're right :). Same result with this in index.php:
```<?php
session_start();
exit('Sorry, Brad.);
```

Comment: So I suppose the moral of the story is... if you don't like the default behavior, you can change it in your php.ini file. :)

Comment: Yep! Sorry for wasting your time.

The whole reason this came up is I was playing around with Varnish w/ Craft and by default it bypasses when it gets a `Cache-control: no-cache` response.

Comment: Not a waste at all. We both learned something!

Comment: @TimKelty I would definitely recommend **not** changing this from php.ini as it will have unintended consequences. If you don’t like PHP’s default behavior you should just start explicitly setting what you want using the [{% header %}](http://buildwithcraft.com/docs/templating/header) tag.

Comment: Pfft... LIVE ON THE EDGE!

Answer (score 2):

As highlighted in Brad Bell's answer, those headers are likely set by PHP. By default PHP has the `session_cache_limiter()` method set to `nocache`. You can verify this in your Craft admin panel under `Utilities > PHP Info > session.cache_limiter`.

If you change this value to `public`, it will set a cache expiry according to the value of `session.cache_expire` (set to `180` by default). This is explained [here](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.session-cache-limiter.php) in the PHP docs.

I did not heed Brandon Kelly's advice, and I set `session.cache_limiter=public` in my php.ini file. I do not know which unintended consequences he speaks of, but I like to live dangerously.

Here are the new headers I get:

```
Cache-Control: public, max-age=10800
Expires: Wed, 27 Nov 2019 11:54:38 GMT (180 minutes from now)
```

If you do this, it will break a few things in the admin. Admin pages won't always load properly because the wrong things will be cached. It works perfectly on the website though.

Answer (score 0):

This had me confused for a while: if you're using [Craft Nitro](https://getnitro.sh/), the Nginx config adds `Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache ...` headers which cannot by overridden from PHP or Twig.

In Nitro 1.x you could SSH into the machine and edit the Nginx config to not add the headers. I haven't been able to get Nitro 2.0 to work and have switched to Docker Compose which is simpler and doesn't have this caching problem.